# equivalent of ruby `block_given?` in crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Ruby has this method called the `block_given` in it so that we can check to see if a block is passed and process accordingly if given. Is there an equivalent method in crystal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal How to check if the block argument is given inside the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190854/crystal-how-to-check-if-the-block-argument-is-given-inside-the-function)

Answer (score 8):

Crystal [does not have](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/1013) it for a moment. But you can have similar behavior using method overloading:

```
def foo
  foo {}
end

def foo
  yield
end

foo { }
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *absolutely must* know whether a block was given, you can do something like this:

```
def foo(block : (String ->)? = nil)
  if block
    block.call("Block given")
  else
    puts "No block given"
  end
end

def foo(&block : String ->)
  foo(block)
end

foo { |s| puts s  }
foo
```

(For more information on `Proc` syntax, see https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/type_grammar.html#proc)

Comment: fn's answer code not run on Crystal 1.6.1 anymore, but the key point is correct. following is working code. https://forum.crystal-lang.org/t/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ruby-block-given/5059/3?u=zw963